# How to call a method for object from a set of objects?

Tags: java, collections, set

```
        Map<LocalDate, Set<Meeting>> meetings = new HashMap<LocalDate, Set<Meeting>>();
```

I have a hashmap that stores the date as key and Set of Meeting Class as value.

```
        Collection<Set<Meeting>> insideMeeting = meetings.values();
        System.out.println("meetings and their dates " + Arrays.asList(meetings));      
        System.out.println("How many meetings are there for date? " + insideMeeting);  
        
        for (Iterator<Set<Meeting>> iterator = insideMeeting.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println("value= " + iterator.next());
            }
```

And I am trying to access the said Meeting classes with the same date inside the collection set and compare them.

```
public class Meeting implements Comparable<Meeting>{

    private String employeeId;

    private LocalTime startTime;

    private LocalTime finishTime;

    public Meeting(String employeeId, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime finishTime) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.finishTime = finishTime;
    }


    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getFinishTime() {
        return finishTime;
    }

    public int compareTo(Meeting that) {
        Interval meetingInterval = new Interval(startTime.toDateTimeToday(), 
                finishTime.toDateTimeToday());
        Interval toCompareMeetingInterval = new Interval(that.getStartTime().
                toDateTimeToday(), that.getFinishTime().toDateTimeToday());

        if(meetingInterval.overlaps(toCompareMeetingInterval)){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return this.getStartTime().compareTo(that.getStartTime());
        }

    }
}
```

Basically, if I could I want to compare the meetings (so there are no overlapping meetings in a single day. Let's say someone booked a room for a meeting at 9 am - 11 am and someone else booked the meeting from 10 am - 11 am. We wouldn't want the second request.) Do something like for each set of meetings in the collection I want to compare them with each other. I do have a compareTo method in the Meeting class.

[DEBUG HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Je7.png)

```
meetings and their dates [{2011-03-21=[office.Meeting@4690b489, office.Meeting@363ee3a2]}]
How many meetings are there for date? [[office.Meeting@4690b489, office.Meeting@363ee3a2]]
value= [office.Meeting@4690b489, office.Meeting@363ee3a2]
```

Comment: It sounds like you know how to get a `Set<Meeting>` of the meetings from any given day.  So the `Map` doesn't actually have any relevance here.  (But that said, your `compareTo` method violates its contract and will cause _extremely strange_ behavior when used in a `Set`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for replying. If you could explain what you mean by violating the contract?

Comment: You _cannot_ have a valid `compareTo` method which treats any time intervals that overlap as equal.  That violates the [transitivity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) property.  When used in a `Set`, I can only imagine the bugs that'd cause.  It'd start with it being nondeterministic which of an overlapping set gets chosen; then you'd start having elements in the set that actually turn out to compare as equal, then everything would start breaking down.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I would still need a way to compare the meetings class in the same date. How would you suggest I go on to access the meeting class and compare first class's info to second's

Comment: Compare them for what purpose?

Comment: Well, I was suggesting ways to simplify your question and eliminate extra details.  But the easiest way is to write `(for (Meeting meeting1 : set) { for (Meeting meeting2 : set) { doSomething(meeting1, meeting2); } }`.

Comment: @shmosel so there are no overlapping meetings in a single day. Let's say someone booked a room for a meeting at 9 am - 11 am and someone else booked the meeting from 10 am - 11 am. We wouldn't want the second request.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var entry : meetings.values()) {
   for (Meeting meeting : entry) {
      //do whatever with meeting here
   }
}
```

This is how you would loop through each set in your map, and then through each Meeting in your set. It's important to remember that your map will contain several collections, and so you must access one using a key or loop through all of them like here.

Comment: YES!! this is what I am looking for. I just need a little more help. How can I compare the first meeting object's information to the second object's info? Like how u compare with array[0] < array[1]

Comment: Because you're using a Set to contain the Meetings, there's no way to directly access the 0th, 1st, 2nd etc element of the set. You would have to create another for loop that again loops through the same set. Honestly it sounds rather complicated to solve the solution like this. Can you just check if a meeting is valid as you insert it? Or are you required to validate a set? If so, do you need to use a set collection-type, or can you use an arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd personally do it if you really wanted to use an iterator.

```
        Iterator<Meeting> it = insideMeeting.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Meeting current = it.next();
            it.forEachRemaining(testMeeting -> {
                if(current.getStartTime() == testMeeting.getStartTime() ||
                   current.getFinishTime() == testMeeting.getStartTime() /*Add rest of conditions*/){                               
                    //.remove whichever one you want
                }
            });
        }
```

Although, as @studmoobs pointed out this is a bit complicated. I'm sure there'd be a better way of doing it without specifically a set. Like for example any indexed list.